# Prove/disprove if $a,b\Rightarrow c$ then $(a\Rightarrow c) \vee (b\Rightarrow c)$ and vice versa

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Let $a,b,c$ be statements, $\Rightarrow$ is a tautological consequence.
>
> Prove/disprove:
>
> 1. if $a, b\Rightarrow c$ then is it necessarily $a\Rightarrow c$ or $b\Rightarrow c$ ?
> 2. if $(a\Rightarrow c$ or $b\Rightarrow c)$ then is it necessarily $a, b\Rightarrow c$ ?

I think both are true,

1. since both $a,b$ are true then both $a\vee b$ are true and the tautology holds.
2. suppose WLOG $a$ is false, then we have a trivial implication with $a,b\Rightarrow c$

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but what is $a,b$ ? I've never seen "$,$" as a logical symbol.

Comment: @peterh ","= and.

Comment: You've completely changed the question. And I don't know what you mean now, but the first version of the question made perfect sense with commas instead of $\land$. Now it still makes sense, but it asks something different. I was writing an answer, but now I can't be bothered with it. Make up your mind.

Comment: @GitGud the commas and $\wedge$ have the same meaning, $a,b,c\Rightarrow x$ is the same as $a\wedge b\wedge c\Rightarrow x$

Comment: @GinKin No, not usually.

Comment: @GitGud I'll revert it back to commas, I learned they have the same meaning. What is the difference anyway?

Comment: @GinKin I'll copy and paste here the relevant part of my unposted answer which deals with that. Recall that saying that a formula $\phi$ being a tautological consequence of set of formulas $\Gamma$ is, by definition, saying that any valuation that makes all formulas of $\Gamma$ true, also makes $\phi$ true. A couple of common abbreviations of this are $\Gamma \models \phi$ and $\Gamma \implies \phi$. (...)

Comment: (...) To address a comment made in the question, when $\Gamma$ is finite, i.e., when $\Gamma=\{\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi _n\}$ for some natural number $n$ and some formulas $\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi_n$, instead of $\{\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi _n\}\implies \phi$ it's common to write $\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi _n\implies \phi$.
It is true that $\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi _n\implies \phi$ if, and only if, $\phi _1\land \ldots \land\phi _n\implies\phi$, but they are different assertions in principle. In one of them, $\Gamma$ has $n$ statements, in the other $\Gamma$ has one statement.

Comment: @GitGud If I understood correctly, with the $\wedge$ you can't split the statements to "or" like in 1. Well, at least can you tell me if was right or wrong please?

Comment: @GinKin I don't get your proposed solutions. If I may ask, are you following any text book? Which?

Comment: @GitGud no book.. I also checked with my instructors and induktio's answer is wrong since a tautological consequence can't be treated like a logical implication or a part of a proposition.

Comment: @GinKin Your instructors are correct. Can you rewrite the problem WORD for WORD? I very much doubt your instructor would write $(a\Rightarrow c) \color{red}\vee (b\Rightarrow c)$

Comment: @GitGud there's the word "or" there instead. That's basically the same I assumed.

Comment: @GinKin It isn't conceptually the same.

Comment: @GitGud edited, now it's completely identical.

Comment: Very bad etiquette to keep changing the question the way you are without stating updates, especially when there are one or more answers that you make useless by your edits.

Comment: @GinKin I'm not sure exactly on how formal your course is, so it's hard to help appropriately. But I get the impression that you don't understand some fundamental concepts. This was suggested by the comma issue and using $\lor$ instead of 'or'. Do you know what propositional symbols or propositional atoms are? Do you know the definition of formula? Do you know what a valuation is?

Comment: @GitGud I'm not from an English speaking country so we use different names and sometimes I don't know the direct translation of a term to English, but I checked and I'm pretty sure we've seen all of what you mentioned. It's an introductory course, not 'pure logic'.

Comment: @GinKin I tried answering the question. It may look too technical, but it's important that you deal with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that saying that a formula $\phi$ being a tautological consequence of set of formulas $\Gamma$ is, by definition, saying that **any** [valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_%28logic%29) that makes all formulas of $\Gamma$ true, also makes $\phi$ true. A couple of common abbreviations of this are $\Gamma \models \phi$ and $\Gamma \implies \phi$.

To address a comment made in the question, when $\Gamma$ is finite, i.e., when $\Gamma=\{\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi _n\}$ for some natural number $n$ and some formulas $\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi_n$, instead of $\{\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi _n\}\implies \phi$ it's common to write $\phi _1, \ldots ,\phi _n\implies \phi$.

Back to your question, let $a,b,c$ be formulas.

The first one doesn't necessarily hold. For an explicit counterexample consider two propositional atoms $p,q$ and define $a=p$, $b=q$ and $c=p\land q$ (with the appropriate conventions so that $c$ is actually a formula). Now prove that $a,b\implies c$ (I suggest you do this proving every detail) and note that neither $a\implies c$ (because of the valuation $v$ such that $v(p)=1$ and $v(q)=0$), nor $b\implies c$ hold (similar).

The second one holds and you can even relax the hypothesis. It holds that if $a\implies c$, then $a,b\implies c$. Assume that $a\implies c$, i.e., suppose that $$\text{for all valuations $v$, if $v(a)=1$, then $v(c)=1$}.$$ The goal is to prove that $$\text{for all valuations $v$, if $v(a)=1$ and $v(b)=1$, then $v(c)=1$}.$$

I'm hoping that me having written the problem more explicitly will be help enough for you to prove it.

Comment: Thank you. There isn't much left to do: if $a=b=T$ we're done, if $a=T, b=F$ we have $F\to T = T$. Either way, $c=T$. and that's it (?)

Comment: @GinKin That's not how I'd write it because $a,b,c$ are formulas, they can't equal $T$ or $F$. What I have in mind is something like this. First I prove that $a,b\implies c$. Let $v$ be a valuation such that $v(a)=1$ and $v(b)=1$. Then, by the definition of $a$ and $b$, $v(p)=1$ and $v(q)=1$, therefore, by definition of valuation, $v(c)=v(p\land q)=\min(v(p), v(q))=1$, which proves that $a,b\implies c$.For the rest, I'd use this terminology and notation instead of saying $a=T$ and stuff like that. I've edited the given example, made it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In 1: "If flight number XYZ goes down in flames, and I am on it, then I will die."

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted but it's a pretty simple and clear counter example.